# How do I do copy and paste in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a right-mouse click menu which will have "Copy" and "Paste" options.

Let's say I have:

```
int p=int.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(""));
p*=100;
Box b=new Box();//This is a form called "Box" that has a textbox in it. The result will be in the textbox.
b.Show();
```

So now, I want to let the user copy/paste in the box via a right-click menu. How do I do this?
I am using WinForms.

Comment: Are you using WinForms/WPF/something else? You'll have to provide some more information.

Comment: Pretty much every GUI toolkit (e.g. windows Forms, WPF...) should do this by default already. Which GUI toolkit are you using,

Comment: it is available by default if you use winforms.

Comment: The answer is unclear, as this is a default behavior of the Windows Forms using the WinAPI. As you are surely aware of. Do you want a custom menu?

Comment: This is WinForms. I want a default menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this behaviour is called `ContextMenu` which will appear on `RightMouseClick`.
as your question is unclear it is available on `TextBox` if you are using Windows `Forms` Application.

Default `ContextMenu` on Windows `Form`

[image: Default <code>ContextMenu</code>]

If you want to create it some where on the Windows Form you can use `ContextMenuStrip` Control.

See this : [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: And the ContextMenu will do Copy and Paste for me?

Comment: you mean Default ContextMenu? withdefault ContetMenu - yes can do copy and paste.

Comment: I don't see the `RightMouseClick` event for `textBox`

Comment: RightMouseClick means it's on Output window as above image in my naswer not from development Environment Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Is it also possible for listBox?

Comment: No it's not possible for listbox.